# Rails Carrier Wave and JQuery Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery, carrierwave

I am wondering why I always get this kind of error in firebug when I try to upload an image/images. I am using it as on this tutorial.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V5.

And I endedup having this error, the first get request error is automatically appearing when I load the page, and the second POST is when I hit the Start upload:

[image]

Even though I had does errors I successfully uploaded the images when I hit the refresh button

Any Comment or Suggestions are much appriciated..
Thank You.

Comment: Flash uploader may not have necessary session information if this system works behind any authentication.

Comment: Can you show us the headers from the requests and maybe the relevant bits from development.log?

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo app for Rails 3.2.8 and that JS uploader. Its a simple case and you can learn a lot from it:

https://github.com/jalagrange/bootstrap_uploader

Hope this helps!